# MongoDB incorrect results with elemMatch and date fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52da43cd6f0a61e8a5059aaf"),
    "assignments" : [
        {
            "project" : "abc",
            "start" : ISODate("2012-12-31T18:30:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2013-06-29T18:30:00Z")
        },
        {
            "project" : "efg",
            "start" : ISODate("2013-06-30T18:30:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2014-03-30T18:30:00Z")
        }
    ],
    "eid" : "123",
    "name" : "n1",
    "uid" : "u1"
}
```

i am trying to find all the assignments starting after a certain date with the following query. but the returned data is confusing and doesnt look correct. pl help me understand what am i doing wrong.

```
> db.test.find( {uid:'u1'},{ assignments: { $elemMatch: {end: {$gte: new Date(2011,5,1) } } }} ).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52da43cd6f0a61e8a5059aaf"),
    "assignments" : [
        {
            "project" : "abc",
            "start" : ISODate("2012-12-31T18:30:00Z"),
            "end" : ISODate("2013-06-29T18:30:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

should it return both the projects?

Answer (score 5):

The [`$elemMatch` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) limits the results to the first matching array element per document.

If you want to return all matching array elements you can use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
db.courses.aggregate(
    // Find matching documents (would benefit from an index on `{uid: 1}`)
    { $match : {
        uid:'u1'
    }},

    // Unpack the assignments array
    { $unwind : "$assignments" },

    // Find the assignments ending after given date
    { $match : {
        "assignments.end": { $gte: ISODate("2011-05-01") }
    }}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$elemMatch` limits projections in the following way.
Say you have a collection with these documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "prices" : [ 50, 60, 70 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "prices" : [ 80, 90, 100 ] }
```

```
db.t.find({},{'prices':{$elemMatch:{$gt:50}}})
```

Returns:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "prices" : [ 60 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "prices" : [ 80 ] }
```

The projection is curtailed to the first element that is matched, rather than all elements that are matched.
If you were expecting a result like this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "prices" : [ 60,70] }
{ "_id" : 2, "prices" : [ 80, 90, 100 ] }
```

It is not possible with projections which only supports `$elemMatch`, `$` and `$slice`.
For example, you can use, for example, $all in the projection or any other smart projection.

If you want to shape the document, match, filter, project with an unwind and wind (via grouping).

```
aggregate([ {$unwind:'$prices'},{$match:{'prices':{$gt:50}}},{$group:{_id:'$_id',prices:{$push:'$prices'}}}])
```

This will result in what we're looking for.

```
{ "_id" : 2, "prices" : [ 80, 90, 100 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "prices" : [ 60, 70 ] }
```

You can take this pattern and use it for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

With that query you are searching documents with uid = u1 and projecting the results to show only the first element that has a date greater than Date(2011,5,1). Check [$elemMatch projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

I think you need something like this:

```
db.test.find( 
{
    uid:'u1'
    "assignments.end": {$gte: new Date(2011,5,1)} 
}).pretty();
```

Comment: i think the needing to use the aggregation frame work and project is probably needed. will check more and update the thread